# Existence of stick breaking representations for random measures

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, bayesian-probability, random-permutations

The Dirichlet process has a roughly size ordered representation in terms of beta random variables, called a stick-breaking representation [(Sethuraman, 1994)](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A4n216.pdf). Similar results hold for the beta process, the Hierarchical Dirichlet process [(Teh et al., 2006)](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214506000000302) and the Pitman-Yor process [(Ishwaran and James, 2001)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214501750332758). Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of stick breaking representations for various random measures?

Comment: How do you define a stick breaking representation? Is it just what you get from combining a countable sample taking independently from some distribution and combining it with a distribution on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I don't think there's a rigorous definition of stick-breaking, but that's what I'm looking for, yes.